# How to combine results from two different tables using sql

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have four tables,

1. Customers
2. Orders
3. Order-items
4. Sales

"Orders" table contains the status of the order "Complete" or "Processing" When ever an order get completed I store the sales info in a sales table an mark order as complete and also store the total amount and balance in sales table.
Now I want to get customer name with amount due from orders table and balance for each customer from sales table.
I have used this query but no able to get the desired results.

The output is:

[image: current output]

And the desired output is:

[image: desired output]

```
Select c.Name As CustomerName, c.ContactNumber AS CustomerContactNumber, c.Location AS CustomerAddress, Sum(oi.Amount) As Amount 
from OrderItems oi 
  inner join Orders o on oi.OrderId=o.Id 
  inner join Customers c on o.CustomerId=c.Id 
Where o.Status=='Processing' Group By o.CustomerId

UNION

Select c.Name As CustomerName, c.ContactNumber AS CustomerContactNumber, c.Location AS CustomerAddress,SUM(s.Balance) As Balance 
from Sales s 
  inner join Customers c on s.CustomerId=c.Id 
Group By s.CustomerId
```

Comment: Please delete all the external image links and instead include all relevant data to your question directly _in the question_.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to `union`, you can use `left join`, to join `sum(sales)` to your customer `orders` table.

```
Select c.Name As CustomerName
    , c.ContactNumber AS CustomerContactNumber
    , c.Location AS CustomerAddress
    , Sum(oi.Amount) As Amount
    , Sum(t2.Balance) As Balance    
from OrderItems oi 
inner join Orders o on oi.OrderId=o.Id 
inner join Customers c on o.CustomerId=c.Id 
left join
    (Select s.CustomerId
        , SUM(s.Balance) As Balance 
        from Sales s 
        inner join Customers c on s.CustomerId=c.Id 
        Group By s.CustomerId) t2 on t2.CustomerId = c.CustomerId
where o.Status=='Processing' 
Group By c.CustomerId, c.ContactNumber, c.Location
```

Comment: It calculates incorrect balance and amount,the problem is with the order status as i apply where on status the due amount comes from orders with "Processing" and Balance is with order status "Complete"

Comment: how about joining your orders table into the sales?